# Wordpress masking multiple urls to the single page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress (4.0) site and the situation where multiple URLs are dynamically created. Something like this:

```
/api-page/111/222/
/api-page/aaa/bbb/
```

I need to point them to:

```
/api-page/?param1=111&param2=222
/api-page/?param1=aaa&param2=bbb
```

because only the "api-page" exists. On the "api-page" I have the shortcode that will handle the params.

I know how to redirect URLs with an htaccess file, but I need urls to stay as they are.

I manage to mask the urls with this line in an htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^api-page/(.+)/(.+)/$ /api-page/?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L]
```

But WordPress throws 404 errors.

How to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you please explain why you downvoted my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The solution not using htaccess. I put this snippet in the function.php file of the theme:

```
function api_rw_rules() {    
    global $wp; 
    $wp->add_query_var('param1');   
    $wp->add_query_var('param2');
    add_rewrite_rule('api-page/(.+)/(.*)','index.php?pagename=api-page&param1=$matches[1]&param2=$matches[2]','top');
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'api_rw_rules');
```

Last two lines in the function can be removed after setting rewrite rules

```
/*
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
*/
```

The only downside of this solution is that variables are not available in the $_GET. They are available with get_query_var():

```
$param1 = get_query_var('param1');
$param2 = get_query_var('param2');
```